# iframe alignment

Tags: html

This is my page source:

```
<html style="height: 100%">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/public/stylesheets/main.css">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0px">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <img src="/public/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <iframe id="testFrame" src="/public/site_down.gif" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100" width="100">

    </body>
</html>
```

The code below shows the logo in center of page in Firefox, but left aligned in IE. How do i make it browser independant so that it always shows in center?

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>
        <img src="/public/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo" />
    </th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The iframe code is left aligned in Firefox and IE, with IE showing V scroll bar, Firefox does not. I want to make iframe flexible so that the client can drop any image/html code so that it will always be centered without any scroll bars showing up.

My css

```
table
{
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

td
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Tables should never be used for layouts. Go to the back of the class.

Comment: @ Diodeus: Thanks for that suggestion. As class is on break, any other good suggestion? The table part I understand your comment. Looking for any guidance on the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centered pages generally work like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
     ...your side contents...
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

The same technique can be used to center anything, including your image and your Iframe. Give it a class or ID and apply the same CSS pattern.